# Why does name column in mysql table end up blank without inserted name?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, drupal-6

When I run this code, a row in the mysql database table student_log is created. However, the student_name column is not filled with the user entered value. What's going on that is wrong?

```
    <?php

function student_grant_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['student_grant/form'] = array(
    'title' => t('student_grant'),
    'page callback' => 'student_grant',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'description' => t('student_grant'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function student_grant_form() {
  return drupal_get_form('student_grant_my_form');
}

function student_grant_my_form($form_state) {
  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Name'),
    '#size' => 30, 
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );



  // Adds a simple submit button that refreshes the form and clears its contents -- this is the default behavior for forms.
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',

  );
  return $form;
}

// name of table is student_log and field is student_name. Name passed from form_state is put in student_name field?
 function student_grant_my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  db_query("INSERT INTO {student_log} (student_name) VALUES ('%s')", 
  $form_state['name']);
  drupal_set_message(t('Your form has been saved.'));

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be looking at $form_state['values'], like this:

```
function student_grant_my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  db_query("INSERT INTO {student_log} (student_name) VALUES ('%s')", 
  $form_state['values']['name']);
  drupal_set_message(t('Your form has been saved.'));

}
```

Comment: bc: '#default_value' => $form_state['values']['name']?

Comment: There's a pretty good explanation of $form_state here: http://drupal.org/node/751826  They almost never mention anything but $form_state['values'], but there are other array elements in form_state, e.g. $form_state['redirect'].